# How can this search code be improved?

Tags: mysql

I have this search code to search descriptions and alt texts of images in my Wordpress (MySQL) database. However I need it to search a bit "better" and I'm wondering how it could be improved.

Example:
Typical descriptions of a bird image would be: "big birds blue heron large great blue flying flight in flight"

Currently, the code below will find a matching image description using any of those words alone. However, if I combine "great blue heron" as the search words I get nothing.

I'm thinking some SQL wizards out there might see a reasonably easy way to widen the search capabilities through modifying the query methods in the code. If you can help I would be very appreciative :)

```
class WPSSearchImages
{
function __construct() {
    //NOP
}

//Searches all gallery photos using a keyword and returns an array of results containing post IDs (ie, image IDs)
static function perform_gallery_keyword_search($keyword)
{
    //Handles the keyword search of galleries and photos
    global $wpdb;

    //Clear the previous search result array if it exists
    WPSSession::drop("last_search_results");
    WPSSession::drop("last_search_term");

    //Perform queries and collect the results

    //1) Search image description and alt text
    $subquery1 = "$wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '%$keyword%'"; //Takes care of the post content part
    $subquery2 = "$wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_wp_attachment_image_alt' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%$keyword%'"; //Takes care of image alt text part
    $main_subquery = $subquery1 . " OR " . $subquery2;
    $querystr = "
        SELECT DISTINCT $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
        FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
        WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
        AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_wpps_gallery_id' 
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'attachment'
        AND $main_subquery
        ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta.post_id ASC
     ";

    $results1 = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, ARRAY_A);

    //2) Search image caption/excerpt
    $subquery1 = "$wpdb->posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%$keyword%'"; //Takes care of the image caption part
    $querystr = "
        SELECT DISTINCT $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
        FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
        WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
        AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_wpps_gallery_id' 
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'attachment'
        AND $subquery1
        ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta.post_id ASC
     ";

    $results2 = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, ARRAY_A);

    //3) Search image title
    $subquery1 = "$wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '%$keyword%'"; //Takes care of the image title
    $querystr = "
        SELECT DISTINCT $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
        FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
        WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
        AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_wpps_gallery_id' 
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'attachment'
        AND $subquery1
        ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta.post_id ASC
     ";

    $results3 = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, ARRAY_A);

    //4) Search image name
    $subquery1 = "$wpdb->posts.post_name LIKE '%$keyword%'"; //Takes care of the image title
    $querystr = "
        SELECT DISTINCT $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
        FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
        WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
        AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_wpps_gallery_id' 
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'attachment'
        AND $subquery1
        ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta.post_id ASC
     ";

    $results4 = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, ARRAY_A);

    //Let's merge all result arrays
    $merged = array_merge($results1, $results2, $results3, $results4);
    if(empty($merged)){
        return false;
    }
    //Extract only the post id and put into array
    $s_data = array();
    foreach($merged as $res)
    {
        $s_data[] = $res['post_id'];
    }
    $unique_results = array_unique($s_data); //Remove duplicates
    //Store result array in session variable
    if(empty($unique_results)){
        return null;
    }else{
        $searched_photos_array = WPSGalleryItem::getSearchedPhotoItemsArray($unique_results);
        WPSSession::set("last_search_results", $searched_photos_array);
        WPSSession::set("last_search_term", $keyword);
        return $searched_photos_array;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE` matches that start with a leading `%` imply a sequential search. If you can find a way to avoid that you will get a massive improvement.

I'm also wondering whether your operator precedence is correct. I believe the entirety of `$main_subquery` should be in parentheses:

```
$main_subquery = "(". $subquery1 . " OR " . $subquery2 .")";
```